# Groovy equivalent for Chr(34) in vbscript

Tags: java, groovy, casting

How do I represent a double quotes character in groovy the same way I use (char)34 in Java?

Comment: Chr(34) in Java? Isn't that VB?

Comment: Under what circumstances would you need this? In other words, what are you doing? It's relatively unusual.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just do

```
char c = (char)34
```

As you would with Java

Comment: In Groovy it is rather unusual to use character literals. I'd use GStrings all the way.